# Why does the shape of water flowing down from a squared orifice looks like a chain?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, flow, surface-tension

Hello I'm a high school student in Taiwan. My classmate and I are doing a project about the shape of water flowing down from a squared orifice, something like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOuai2p3qgw).

We wanna know  is there a **function** to describe the shape of flow, like we could find the coordinate of every point? Or the relation between the shape and the area of orifice and different kinds of liquid? Is there a **theory** which describes this?

We will be very grateful if anybody could help us, and sorry I'm not very good at English, so maybe there're some mistakes in my English.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113314/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I couldn't find the page of John Bush's gallery...and there's no equation of the shape.

Comment: Is it related to Rayleigh-Plateau Instability?I found another similar question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/512145/
But the answer didn't mentioned the equation of the shape ,maybe like r=const*coskz cosnθ?